# how to compare two HashMap<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, excel, jdbc, hashmap, apache-poi

i want to compare data read from an excel file(key is column 1, value is column 2) that is being put into a HashMap with data obtained from SQL query. At first i did it using HashMap< String, String> because i had to compare only < key, value> pairs, but now i have to compare < key, list> and i am a little stuck. 
Here is my code for reading the xls file:

```
public class ReadExcel {

    HashMap<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

public HashMap<String, List<String>> process() {
    try
    {
        result.clear();

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/some.xlsx"));

        //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        //Iterate through each rows one by one
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();


        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            List<String> xlsList = new ArrayList<String>();

                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Cell cell  = row.getCell(1);
                Cell cell2 = row.getCell(2);
                String key ="";
                String value="";
                xlsList.clear();
                switch (cell.getCellType())
                {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        key = getStringCellValue(cell);
                        value = getNumericCellValue(cell2);
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        key = getStringCellValue(cell);
                        value = getStringCellValue(cell2);
                        break;

                }

                xlsList.add(value);
                result.put(key, xlsList);
        }
    }
}
```

For example in my excel file for

```
row 1: column 1 = car, column 2 = blue
row 2: column 1 = car, column 2 = yellow.
```

When i run the excel reader, it puts the values "blue, yellow" very nice under "car" key in the HashMap.
When i have for example:

```
row 1: column 1 = car,  column 2 = blue
row 2: column 1 = car,  column 2 = yellow
row 3: column 1 = year, column 2 = 1990
row 4: column 1 = year, column 2 = 1999
```

it displays only: `car=[yellow], year=[1999]`. It takes only the last values, this worked fine if it wasn't for the duplicate keys.

First question: How can i do this better? if i got same keys on row 1 to take the key only once and store all the values from row 2 if the key from row 1 is the same?

Here is my code for extracting data from SQL database:

```
public class DB {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

public HashMap<String, List<String>> process() {

    result.clear();

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    List<String> carColour = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql1 = "SOME SQL SELECT STATEMENT THAT RETURNS 2 or more lines, by that i mean "car" has 2 values or more";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);

        while(rs.next()){
            carColour.add(rs.getString("colour")); // i select the column "colour"
            result.put("car", carColour);         // i put "car" as key, and "blue" and "yellow" as values
            ...................................
        }
} catch...
}
```

This code for the DB works ok but if i want to extract more columns, like "colour" or "year", i have to create lists for all of them, and if i got like 20 columns to extract, it could be very time consuming.

Second question: How can i do this easier rather than creating 20 lists?(use the same list maybe and list.clear(); it ?) (here it depends because if i got 30 columns and i need only 20, i can getString("column") all and remove the ones i don't want, but how?

Here is the code for comparison:

```
final Map<String, Boolean> comparisonResult = compareEntries(dbResult, xlsResult);
        for(final Entry<String, Boolean> entry : comparisonResult.entrySet()){
            if (entry.getValue() == false){
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("| Comparison FAILED | Value not matching! Column name --> " + entry.getKey() + " |");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("DB consistency check finished.");
```

................................................................................

```
public static <K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>
Map<K, Boolean> compareEntries(final Map<K, V> dbResult,
    final Map<K, V> xlsResult){
    final Collection<K> allKeys = new HashSet<K>();
    allKeys.addAll(dbResult.keySet());
    allKeys.addAll(xlsResult.keySet());
    final Map<K, Boolean> result = new TreeMap<K, Boolean>();
    for(final K key : allKeys){
        result.put(key, dbResult.containsKey(key) == xlsResult.containsKey(key) && Boolean.valueOf(equal(dbResult.get(key), xlsResult.get(key))));
    }
    return result;
}

private static boolean equal(final Object obj1, final Object obj2){
    return obj1 == obj2 || (obj1 != null && obj1.equals(obj2));
}
```

Last question: how can i improve the code to compare two HashMap(String, List< String>), or how can i do this better step by step? Thank you!

Comment: If you just need to check equal/not equal, I'd be inclined to get both sets of data into identical data types and then write a recursive `objectsAreEqual(Object obj1, Object obj2)` method to compare the two "trees".

Comment: Inside the iterator loop in `ReadExcel`, you're always creating a new `List` (`xlsList`). That's why every list contains only one (the last) value in the end.

Comment: Maybe, more convenient way is to handle this on DB level, using SQL? Why did you decide to export data from DB instead of importing data into temporary table and perform SQL?

Comment: For refactoring your DB class, how open are you using spring jdbc library?

Comment: very open, if it is easier to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ReadExcel` reading loop has a severe problem: Instead of reusing a `List`, that is already mapped by a key, you're always creating a new one, hence you'll end up having lists with only one single (the last) value.

This is how you can fix this (using Java 8):

```
// ...
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    Cell keyCell = row.getCell(1);
    Cell valCell = row.getCell(2);

    String key = getStringCellValue(keyCell);
    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            value = getNumericCellValue(valCell);
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            value = getStringCellValue(valCell);
            break;
        }
    }

    // this line only compiles since Java 8
    result.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<Object>()).add(value);
}
```

If you don't use Java 8 yet, download it quickly, or replace the last line above with:

```
Set<Object> list = result.get(key);
if (list == null) result.put(key, list = new HashSet<Object>());
list.add(value);
```

Comparison of `Map` objects is rather easy - you can directly compare them using `equals`:

```
if (map1.equals(map2)) {
    // both maps are equal!
} else {
    // maps are NOT equal!
}
```

Of course, this only yields `true` or `false`. If you want to know details (which entries differ), you will need to do it by yourself.

Comment: Doing like this will not work outside the while loop, only inside it, and still i get: Type mismatch cannot convert from List<String> to Set<Object> .
 
 Set<Object> list = result.get(key);
 if (list == null) result.put(key, list = new HashSet<Object>());
 list.add(value);

Comment: That's because your result map is of type `HashMap<String, List<String>>`, but it should be `HashMap<String, Set<Object>>` now.